# Is $\{-2,2\}$ a group under $a\star b=\max\{a,b\}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition, monoid

Lets say $G={-2,2}$ and $a*b=\text{max}\{a,b\}$.
I need to check if this is a group
and if it does than is it abelian or not and finite or not.

Well... first, I'm not sure if this is a group.  for $-2,2$ I'll always get the same result so can I say there is identity number??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, let's talk about it.

A group $G$ needs three things.

1. *Identity*:  There must be an element $e\in G$ so that $e\star g=g\star e=g$ for all $g\in G$.
2. *Inverses*:  For each $g\in G$, there must be an element $g^{-1}\in G$ so that $g^{-1}\star g=g\star g^{-1}=e$.
3. *Associativity*:  For $a,b,c\in G$, $a\star(b\star c)=(a\star b)\star c$.

Your example satisfies $1$ and $3$: $-2$ is an identity, and the operation is clearly associative.  However, there is no inverse for $2$.  So $G$ is not a group.  It is a [monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid), though!

Comment: $\ddot\smile$ +1

Answer (score 7):

There is an identity (with respect to the defined operation): it is $-2$, because we have $\max\{-2,a\}=a$ for any $a \in G$.

But still, $(G, *)$ is not a group. The law that is violated here is the existence of inverse elements: $2$ has no inverse, i.e. there is no such $a \in G$ that $\max\{a,2\}=-2$.

Answer (score 5):

According to @Alexander's answer, it is a monoid instead.

Answer (score 4):

$*$ **is closed on** $\{-2, 2\}$, and is well-defined.

***Associative***: ***yes***

***Identity***: ***yes***, we have $-2$ is an identity (with respect $*$): since $\max\{-2,g\}=g$ for any $g \in G$.

***Closed under Inversion***: ***NO***: $\;2 \in G$ has no inverse, i.e. there is no such $g \in G$ that $\max\{g,2\}=-2$.

The failure of any one of the above conditions negates the prospect of $(G, *)$ being a group. *Since closure under inversion fails*, $(G, *)$ fails to be a group.

---

It's perhaps beside the point, but $*$ is commutative on $G$, and the group is finite, clearly (exactly 2 elements in $G$), so you actually have a ***finite, abelian monoid***!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a group because there is no $c$ such that $c*2=-2$. 
(If $G$ were a group, then we know that $(-2)*(2^{-1})$ would satisfy the property $(-2)*(2^{-1})*(2)=-2$)